# Can I use wild character in file path for NSIS CopyFiles command?

Tags: nsis

I want to copy files during installation to a folder. The path of the folder contains say build number and its not constant.

```
CopyFiles "E:\Source\*.jar" "E:\Destination\Myfiles_22.14.03.25\here"
```

Something like above but my code cannot use absolute path as the version string will change. IS there some way of using wild character * in the file path (E:\Destination\MyFiles_*\here)  and copying files there?

Answer (score 2):

The NSIS `CopyFiles` instruction is a thin wrapper around the [`SHFileOperation`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762164%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function and according to MSDN, wildcards are only supported in the file-name portion of the source path.

To search for files and folders on the end-users system you can use the [`FindFirst`](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/Chapter4.html#4.9.5.13), `FindNext` and `FindClose` instructions...